# Professional word and sentence list for Spanish

Tags: resource-request, spanish

I found [this](https://www.goethe.de/pro/relaunch/prf/en/Goethe-Zertifikat_B1_Wortliste.pdf) excellent German CEFR level B1 word and sentence list from the Goethe Institut, which is a professional institute that promotes the German language worldwide.

Is there a similar free file available for **Spanish**? Anywhere from A2-B2 would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any lists that are available for free, so here are a few resources for which you need to pay:

- Jesús Sánchez Lobato; Rosana Acquaroni Muñoz: [*Vocabulario ELE B1: Léxico fundamental de español de los niveles A1 a B1*](https://ele.sgel.es/ficha_material.asp?id=2406). Alcobendas (Madrid): SGEL, 2014. ISBN: 978-84-9778-495-5. This book covers 2500 words, which are organised thematically. The words are not explained or translated, but for many of them (probably less than half) there are example sentences. There are also exercises for each lesson or theme; an index and an answer key can be found at the back of the book. (You can download a free excerpt.)
- [Zona ELE](https://zonaele.com/): *Lexicón 2016. Usos de español para estudiantes de ELE (español como lengua extranjera)*. This is a PDF document that is 800 pages long and covers 15.292 words. It definitely goes beyond level B2 but can be used as a source of additional usage examples for the previous book.. (You can download a free excerpt.)
- Cristina Palanca; Geir Ståle Tennfjord: [*Lo básico*](https://edinumen.es/material-complementario/vocabulario/espanol-esencial/lo-basico-detalle). Madrid: Edinumen. This book covers vocabulary for the levels A1 and A2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the resources below:

- The Spanish *Kwiziq* website where there are vocabulary themes divided by levels (from entry level to C1 level) --> https://spanish.kwiziq.com/learn/theme
- The *Lingolex* website with its Spanish vocabulary lists from beginner to C1 level --> https://www.lingolex.com/swom/
- The *Vocabulario Español Nivel A2* on the *Books4Languages* website --> https://open.books4languages.com/spanish-a2-vocabulary/
- The *Lawless Spanish* website which offers Spanish lessons (which are divided into grammar, listening, pronunciation, reading, vocabulary and pronunciation) from A1 to C1 levels --> https://www.lawlessspanish.com/language-levels/